# PHP C14N() change characters inside CDATA

Tags: php, xml, cdata, c14n

I have an xml that I must sign, however when I send it it has a structure something like this:

```
<cbc:EncodingCode>UTF-8</cbc:EncodingCode>
<cbc:Description>
    <![CDATA[<ApplicationResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2".....
```

After passing it through the conocalization with C14N(), you are like this

```
<cbc:EncodingCode>UTF-8</cbc:EncodingCode>
<cbc:Description>
    &lt;ApplicationResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2"
```

Changing the characters < > by `&gt; &lt;` and remove `<![CDATA[]]>`

What do I do, help?

Comment: It's parsed correctly. Instead of using C14N, you should reach for saveXML. For example: `echo htmlentities($dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('*','Description')[0]->firstChild));`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However the result remains the same. <code>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;ApplicationResponse xmlns=&quot;urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2&quot; xmlns:cac=&quot;urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2&quot;<code>

Comment: Remove the htmlentities. That was for outputting it to browser.

Comment: I see the desired CDATA in the output you're showing with my code.